# Problem creating a ROS package with the presence of external headers

Tags: ros, external-libraries, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am a PhD student and quite new to ROS trying to make a ROS package to use my Robot. The company who built the robot has also provided us some C++ libraries and codes, i.e. libRobot.h and libRobot.cc. Inside these codes there some functions from different classes that help us to read status of the robot and also send commands to it.
For example:

```
int Rover::getSpeed ( Time & _timestamp,
float & _left,
float & _right 
) 

Get the speed of the tracks [in rad/s].

Parameters
[out] _timestamp the current timestamp [in s].
[out] _left the average speed of the front and rear left tracks [in rad/s].
[out] _right the average speed of the front and rear right tracks [in rad/s].
Returns
0 if success, an error code otherwise.
```

Now what I am trying to do is to create a package that executes some of this functions, for example to read the voltage of the battery, and publish the data as ROS messages.
I put the **.h files in my_package/include and the **.cc files in my_package/ directories. I also set up my CMakeLists.txt as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(donkey_rover)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
roscpp
rospy
std_msgs
)
generate_messages(
DEPENDENCIES
std_msgs
)
catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include LIBRARIES donkey_rover 
CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
DEPENDS system_lib
)
include_directories(
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(rovstate src/rovstate.cpp)
target_link_libraries(rovstate
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_dependencies(rovstate donkey_rover_generate_messages_cpp)
add_dependencies(rovstate ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

When I put my header in my cpp file, (i.e. #include libRobot.h) the catkin_make process fails at the very last second:

```
[ 98%] Built target navfn_node
[ 98%] Built target navtest
[100%] Built target global_planner
[100%] Built target move_base_node
[100%] Built target planner
make[2]: *** [donkey_rover/CMakeFiles/rovstate.dir/src/rovstate.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [donkey_rover/CMakeFiles/rovstate.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

Do you have any idea how can I possibly solve the problem?

Thank you very much in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217804/problem-creating-a-ros-package-with-the-presence-of-external-headers/) by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 397 on 2015-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution to this problem can be find in this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/218015/problem-in-determining-a-link-language-while-using-external-libraries/).

---

Originally posted by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) with karma: 397 on 2015-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the next time, please try to find the relevant lines where the error is detailed.
From your post, we only see there is an error.

However, there are several problems with your `CMakeLists.txt`.

You need to tell the compiler where to find the headers you include.
So adapt the following lines in your `CMakeLists.txt` from:

```
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

to

```
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

But I guess you will also need to add the library source file to the `add_executable` call, so:

```
add_executable(rovstate src/rovstate.cpp src/libRobot.cc)
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2